# Automatically write changelog to CHANGELOG.md in GitHub

Tags: git, github, changelog

Is there any way to automatically generate change logs from commit messages to a file called CHANGELOG.md in a GitHub repo?

Might be possible using a service hook on a repo?

Answer (score 8):

I have written something like this some months ago. It is based on Git's porcelain and uses a git hook in plain bash.

You can find it in my [Github Repo](https://github.com/MartinSeeler/auto-changelog-hook).

Comment: So, are the changes in the changelog commited together with the commit or not?

Comment: Yes, they are. Thats the reason why it ammends the changes to the commit.

Answer (score 3):

Since the [May 2013 File CRUD API](https://github.com/blog/1498-file-crud-and-repository-statistics-now-available-in-the-api) with [this API](http://developer.github.com/changes/2013-05-06-create-update-delete-individual-files/), it should be possible to script it by:

- parsing the git log message
- using the result to update the `CHANGELOG.md` file

See [Update file](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file):

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

You actually can trigger that script from a [GitHub post-receive hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks), except that hook won't execute it directly, but POST a JSON message to a server of yours, which, on the reception of that specific message, will know how to update the GitHub `CHANGELOG.md` file (through API call mentioned above).

Comment: You will need to make sure not to create an infinite loop this way, though (Push -> Hook gets activated -> Changelog is updated and pushed -> rinse and repeat). Not impossible, but something one should keep in mind.

Comment: @Polygnome the JSON contains all the information you need to help you differentiate between the two pushes, making sure you won't do anything on the second one.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a GitHub app '[Changelogg.io](https://www.changelogg.io)' to automate changelog from merged pull requests.

It detects changes mentioned in the PRs and creates a release draft for it. After adding the release version, it automatically updates CHANGELOG.md and also has a web UI with filters for the generated changelog.
Few other features:

- Insights generated from changes (Stats like bugs to feature ratio, Trend over time for repository)
- Slack Integration for each repository

[Youtube Walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=17&v=nm2rghSMW1o&feature=emb_title)